# Como medir el tiempo de ejecución de una función que itera cierta cantidad de veces, y los pueda añadir a un arreglo. Python

Tags: python

```
arrsol=[]
timearr=[]



for i in tqdm(range(0,500)):
    A = np.random.randint(-5,5,(n[0],n[0]))
    b = np.random.randint(-5,5,(n[0],1))
    sol=Gauss_Solve(A,b)
    time=%timeit sol
    timearr.append(time)
    arrsol.append(sol)


print(timearr)
```

Cuando intento agregarlos a una lista aparece none... además de esto son 23 minutos esperando que se cuenten todos los tiempos, me parece exagerado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es usando la libreria `timeit` determinar el tiempo de inicio y de final algo asi

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
timearr = []

for i in tqdm(range(0,500)):
    start = timer()
    A = np.random.randint(-5,5,(n[0],n[0]))
    b = np.random.randint(-5,5,(n[0],1))
    sol=Gauss_Solve(A,b)
    end = timer()
    timearr.append(end-start)
    arrsol.append(sol)
```

Con esto se deberia guardar el tiempo de cada iteración en segundos, de igual manera puedes sacar el tiempo total convirtiendo todo en una funcion

```
def iteration():
    for i in tqdm(range(0,500)):
        A = np.random.randint(-5,5,(n[0],n[0]))
        b = np.random.randint(-5,5,(n[0],1))
        sol=Gauss_Solve(A,b)
        arrsol.append(sol)
    return arrsol

start = timer()
result = iteration()
end = timer()
total = end-start
print("El tiempo de ejecucion fue de %s" %total)
```